# Use Redis for Drupal sessions

Tags: 7, sessions, database

I've been looking online for a while and I haven't seen anything on setting up Drupal to use Redis for session handling. I've found tutorials and blogs about settings Redis up as a replacement for Memcached for caching.

Anyone know how to do this? I was hopping there was something in the $conf variable in the settings.php file that would allow me to override where sessions are stored and retrieved.

Thanks for any help in advance,
FatGuyLaughing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a quick google search: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal+redis+sessions

and the 2nd result talks about redis session handling:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2250195

from that issue thread i recommend looking [Session Proxy](https://www.drupal.org/project/session_proxy). This allows you to override the default session handler by Drupal -- which is explained in the above issue:

> This is because Drupal will override your session handler and use its
>   own, it goes straight to the database. I'd recomend that you try using
>   this module: https://drupal.org/project/session_proxy

Session Proxy provides the following, I believe your attempting #2:

> ships three different session managing implementations:
>
> 1. Database session handling: core default, ported to the object oriented
>      API. It comes with an additional SQL query done more than core
>      session.inc default implementation due to the API strong
>      encapsulation.
> 2. Native PHP session handling: by selecting this session
>      management mode, you explicitely remove any core session management,
>      and let PHP manage it. This can be useful if you intend to use
>      low-level PHP extensions, such as Memcache or PhpRedis to handle
>      session in PHP low-level layer instead of core. This allow to use any
>      PHP native session storage to work gracefully: some of them are high
>      performance.
> 3. Cache based storage engine: Using the same session
>      handling than core, but deporting raw session storage into a cache
>      backend instance. You can use any already-functionning cache backend
>      to store sessions. Sessions will use their own bin, and won't be
>      cleared at cache clear all time.

Again from the linked issue after installing session proxy you likely need to configure your php.ini to something like:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://localhost:6379"
```

Comment: Sorry about that, I already googled that phrase and apparently in the mist of looking through all the links I somehow skipped the 2nd one. 

Thanks for pointing that back out to me, it is greatly appreciated.